# C++ - Compile and link multiple files

Tags: c++, compilation

I have a project with the following structure:

```
Item.cpp
Item.h
main.cpp
Makefile
```

The following source code is in the `Item.h` file:

```
class Item {
    public:
        Item();
        ~Item();
};
```

The following source code is in the `Item.cpp` file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Item.h"

Item::Item() {
    std::cout << "Item created..." << std::endl;
}

Item::~Item() {
    std::cout << "Item destroyed..." << std::endl;
}
```

The following source code is the content of the `main.cpp` file:

```
#include "Item.h"

#include <iostream>


int main() {
    std::cout << "Initialize program..." << std::endl;
    Item item_1();
    std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And finally, the following source code is the `Makefile` file:

```
CXX = g++

all: main item
    $(CXX) -o sales.o main.o Item.o

main:
    $(CXX) -c main.cpp

item:
    $(CXX) -c Item.cpp

clean:
    rm -rf *.o
```

When I run the `make` command and then I run the compiled code with the command `./sales.o`, I get the following output:

```
Initialize program...
Hello world!
```

Why is the output of the constructor method of the class `Item` not printed in the console? I found in some web pages that you can compile the source codes in steps and then you can link it with the `-o` option when using `g++` but it does not work in this case. How can I compile this source codes step by step and then link it in the `Makefile`?

Comment: can we have item.h please

Comment: @pm100 I updated the question to add the header file.

Comment: this should be working, are you sure that you are running the program you think you are

Comment: @pm100 Completely sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm surely you ignored this warning :

`warning: empty parentheses were disambiguated as a function declaration [-Wvexing-parse]`

```
#include "Item.h"

#include <iostream>


int main() {
    std::cout << "Initialize program..." << std::endl;
    Item item_1;
    std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

just remove parentheses it will be work
test : https://godbolt.org/z/KrdrhvsrW

Comment: Do you know how to show that warnings using `g++` command?

Comment: lets use `-Wall` flag with g++.

Comment: I check -Wvexing-parse is available at some new g++ version 11.x, lets upgrade or use clang if needed